# Copying Range from Excel efficiently to Word array (VBA)

Tags: vba, performance, ms-word

I'm dealing with some performance issues on word-VBA. I've got an excel sheet which is touched every time when I read out a value from a cell, which leeds to very long execution times.
Is there any more efficient way to read out the excel sheet at once and paste it into an (string?) arrayso that only 1 access to the excel sheet is necessary?
All other operations shall be done by accessing the values in the array.

Greets, poeschlorn

Answer (score 1):

From your description, although I am not sure of the meaning of "touched" in your question, I guess the workbook is being re-calculated upon opening. You could inhibit this behaviour by adding this to the Workbook VBA:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

Just remember that the same will happen when your users open the workbook manually.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, I understand what you want. But on this [Microsoft Support Site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213798) is an explanation of converting an Excel range into an array. The same thing should be possible from Word.

In short:

```
   Sub Sheet_Fill_Array()
      Dim myarray As Variant
      myarray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
      Range("a1:a10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray)
   End Sub
```